# Can't encode struct into JSON in Rust

Tags: rust, rustc-serialize

I'm following an Iron web framework tutorial, which seemed pretty simple, but I can't seem to encode a struct as JSON.

```
extern crate iron;
extern crate rustc_serialize;

use iron::prelude::*;
use iron::status;
use rustc_serialize::json;

struct Greeting {
    msg: String,
}

fn main() {
    fn hello_world(_: &mut Request) -> IronResult<Response> {
        let greeting = Greeting { msg: "hello_world".to_string() };
        let payload = json::encode(&greeting).unwrap();
        // Ok(Response::with((status::Ok,payload)))
    }

    // Iron::new(hello_world).http("localhost:3000").unwrap();
}
```

My Cargo.toml

```
[package]
name = "iron_init"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["mazbaig"]

[dependencies]
iron = "*"
rustc-serialize = "*"
```

And my error:

```
error: the trait bound `Greeting: rustc_serialize::Encodable` is not satisfied [E0277]
        let payload = json::encode(&greeting).unwrap();
                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~
help: run `rustc --explain E0277` to see a detailed explanation
note: required by `rustc_serialize::json::encode`
```

I kinda get that the right types aren't getting passed into the `json.encode()` function, but I'm having trouble figuring out what it wants from me. I'm probably missing something really basic.

Comment: Which tutorial? You need to add `#[derive(RustcEncodable)]` on `Greeting`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't provide the actual tutorial that you are using, but it appears to match [this one from brson](https://github.com/brson/httptest).

```
extern crate iron;
extern crate rustc_serialize;

use iron::prelude::*;
use iron::status;
use rustc_serialize::json;

#[derive(RustcEncodable)]
struct Greeting {
    msg: String
}

fn main() {
    fn hello_world(_: &mut Request) -> IronResult<Response> {
        let greeting = Greeting { msg: "Hello, World".to_string() };
        let payload = json::encode(&greeting).unwrap();
        Ok(Response::with((status::Ok, payload)))
    }

    Iron::new(hello_world).http("localhost:3000").unwrap();
    println!("On 3000");
}
```

Notice anything different between the two?

```
#[derive(RustcEncodable)]
struct Greeting {
    msg: String
}
```

You have to specify that the `Encodable` trait is implemented. In this case, you can do so by deriving `RustcEncodable`.

Comment: Oh okay. Is there a reason why structs aren't encodable by default? Is it an overhead thing?

Comment: @Maz essentially nothing is done "by default" in Rust. One of the benefits of a systems language is that you are aware of all the details of the code you are writing. You may *not* want to make a given struct serializable. A given struct may not be able to be serialized - should that prevent compilation? Give a warning? Fail silently? You can see why opting in is much simpler.